# Same space available after delete file

Tags: java, android, linux, file

I'm having some issues with retrieving available space.
Shortly, I'm writing a file and after I delete it, but the available space is still de same before and after delete. As you can see in the following logs.

```
> 2019-06-26 12:39:42.209 D/RemoveOne: before delete, space is:23220
> 2019-06-26 12:39:42.209 D/RemoveOne: before delete, file path
> /storage/emulated/0/one , exists true , file length 13599232
> 2019-06-26 12:39:42.231 D/RemoveOne: after delete, file path
> /storage/emulated/0/one, exist false, file length 0 2019-06-26
> 12:39:42.232 D/RemoveOne: after delete, space is: 23220
```

Write file with following code:
**!!!Please be careful** , it creates a file to fill all space, **don't RUN** this otherwise you know which are the implications.
I destroy the process when my file has the amount that I need.

```
String[] command = {
         "/system/bin/sh",
         "-c",
         "tr '\\0' '\\377' < /dev/zero | dd of=" + path + "/one" }; 
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); process.waitFor();
```

And the methods that I tried for available space, both display the same:
Variant 1:

```
long meg = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()).getAvailableBytes();
long megAvailable = meg / (1024 * 1024);
return megAvailable;
```

Variant 2:

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long bytesAvailable;
bytesAvailable = stat.getBlockSizeLong() * stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);
return megAvailable;
```

Methods used for delete, both same result :
Variant 1:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
final File file = new File(path + "/one");
Log.d(TAG, "before" + getFreeMemory());
Log.d(TAG, "before" + file.getAbsolutePath() + " " + file.exists() + " " + file.length());
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm " + path + "/one");
process.waitFor();
Log.d(TAG, "after" + file.getAbsolutePath() + " " + file.exists() + " " + file.length());
Log.d(TAG, "after" + getFreeMemory());
```

Variant 2:

```
 String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 File file = new File(path + "/one");
 Log.d(TAG, "before" + getFreeMemory());
 Log.d(TAG, "before" + file.getAbsolutePath() + " " + file.exists() + " " + file.length());
 file.delete();
 Log.d(TAG, "after" + file.getAbsolutePath() + " " + file.exists() + " " + file.length());
 Log.d(TAG, "after" + getFreeMemory());
```

Why is the space the same after delete?

UPDATE:
I have tried , to write the file directly with certain size... 10MB...

```
String[] command = {
           "/system/bin/sh",
           "-c",
           "tr '\\0' '\\377' < /dev/zero | dd of=" + path + "/one bs=1 
           count=10000000"
 };
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
process.waitFor();
```

And after the delete the space is recognised correctly.
So I believe , the onDestroy method , which I was calling to stop writing in file at certain size, doesn't release the file...
I'm trying on this path now to see if it suits my demands...

Comment: I have met something like that when there was a process/service which work at directory (which contains file) or with file directly. When I stopped/killed service/process - space was retrieved. Maybe it can help you

Comment: I have found something like that, that the file is tied to something...maybe there is a way I can find out if it is tied or still opened or something...

Comment: You can check it by ```fuser``` (on Unix. It is a part of psmisc package). You should check both of file using and directory using.
Loo at this article for syntax: ```https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_(Unix)```

Comment: I assume your program creates the file then later deletes it while the program is in its same run? The OS probably still considers the created file attached to your process and doesn't free it up until perhaps the program exits. What happens if you check the free space *after* your program exits?

Comment: Yes operations are in the same run. After I close the app, the space is displayed correctly ...hmmm that means it's still tied to the process that created it ...but what can I do then?

Comment: I think you should destroy process after work, like this:

```Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command");
    p.destroy();
```

Comment: The process that created the file is stopped with onDestroy (when the file is as large as I want) , I tried to do process.destroy() on the delete process itself, after waitFor...still the same space :(

Comment: I run also lsof file, to see if it is tied to process, but it says that file is deleted. For fuser I receive permission denied.(Cannot run program "fuser": error=13, Permission denied)

Comment: Can you attach full class code pls?